# Android MediaPlayer how to handle MediaTimeDiscontinuity?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, wav

I'm writing a Xamarin.Android project. I've got some audio coming from Azure speech synthesis. I save the bytes to a .wav file then when I try to use it as a data source for MediaPlayer I am getting MediaTimeDiscontinuity events. These events seem to be causing the player to freeze. I've looked around for guidance, but I haven't been able to find suggestions for how to handle these events gracefully or how to process the audio to avoid these issues. The audio data is 16 bit Mono PCM with a sample rate of 24000khz

Here's the code for saving the file:

```
        soundFilePath = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory + "/" + audio.GetHashCode() + ".wav";
        var fs = File.Create(soundFilePath);

        fs.Write(audio, 0, audio.Length);
        fs.Flush();
        fs.Close();
```

Here's my code for loading and playing the file:

```
        var attrs = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
            .SetContentType(AudioContentType.Speech)
            .SetLegacyStreamType(Android.Media.Stream.Music)
            .SetUsage(AudioUsageKind.Media)
            .Build();

        var format = new AudioFormat.Builder()
            .SetEncoding(Encoding.Pcm16bit)
            .SetSampleRate(24000)
            .SetChannelMask(ChannelOut.Mono)
            .Build();

        player = new MediaPlayer();
        player.SetAudioAttributes(attrs);
        player.SetDataSource(soundFilePath);
        player.Prepared += (object sender, EventArgs args) =>
        {
            player.Start();
        };

        player.MediaTimeDiscontinuity += (object sender, MediaPlayer.MediaTimeDiscontinuityEventArgs args) =>
        {
            //This code isn't working
            var mp = args.Mp;
            mp.Pause();
            mp.SeekTo((int)args.Mts.AnchorMediaTimeUs / 1000 + 1);
            mp.Start();
        };

        player.PrepareAsync();
```

The .wav files play just fine in other players, and when I open the files in Audacity I don't see any anomalies.

EDIT: forgot to mention that this was using Xamarin native

Also, for more background, I'm running the app on Genymotion using the Pixel 3 profile. I've also tried it on my physical Pixel 2 device

EDIT (10/20/2020): This is still an issue. From the docs, I found that these events occur under the following conditions:

> when the player is starved for data and cannot play anymore
> when the player encounters a playback error
> when the a seek operation starts, and when it's completed
> when the playback speed changes
> when the playback state changes
> when the player is reset

It's definitely not the first or third option as the buffer has the correct size and I never call seek (other than in my handler).

I'm not sure how to even start to debug this either. I get no unhandled exceptions and no errors in logcat or the debug console.

Comment: I test the code you provided. It works well without `MediaTimeDiscontinuity`. What does the `MediaTimeDiscontinuity` do?

Comment: If unhandled, it causes the audio to stop playing altogether. As you can see, I tried manually moving the track forward and attempting to play it again, but it doesn't seem to work. I've got some rendering logic tied to the track position, but the position doesn't get updated after hitting one of these discontinuities. I can't find anything on google about this issue

Comment: I would test it and feedback ASAP.

Comment: According to your code, there is no more information for manully moving. Could you provide more about this?